Concrete foundation cracks on 5 yr old home
Our slab foundation home is about 5 years old now with some issues on the 1st floor where we have bulges and floor planks popping. I pulled up a piece and found a 3/16" wide crack running under the problematic part of the flooring. Walking outside I see a 1/4" crack on the exterior near where the crack under the flooring is located. I'm unsure whether the crack continues all the way to the other side of the foundation.
I know concrete cracks are inevitable, but these seem excessive, does anyone have an opinion whether I should involve a structural engineer?
Pictures for reference: imgur
Location: Southeast US

Opinion, yes get the inspection done, it might be serious

Given your location, there may be ground movement associated with a sinkhole.  Often your insurance will pay for an inspection and needed remediation.
This is something that needs to be inspected closely. However it may be just normal soil settlement and the cracks can be filled.
